# QA Testing automation tools to learn: Selenium, Protractor, Cypress

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, protractor, cypress

I have some programming experience and want to switch to QA roles that suit my skills better, I have more knowledge of Java but some Python.

1. I am wondering if I should focus on Selenium that I have some knowledge of or Protractor or Cypress that are considered as the latest standards?
   I am more of a front end guy as a developer.
2. Also, I generally use guru99, tutorialspoint or w3schools to get started. Any other great resources for free or less expensive for quick learning for these topics?
3. Will cloud upgrades affect this learning process?
   Please advice.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out into each of the major automation tools and see the pros and cons of each in reference to their functionality and applications of successfully implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is still the most wide used web UI automation tool, having a lot of tutorials for any level of experience etc. Also, once you know one tool, you will be able to learn other similar tools in the future easily. Also, Selenium supports and mainly used in programming languages you already know while the other tools you mentioned using JavaScript. So, I'd advice you to start (and then continue) with Selenium.

Comment: It definitely is one of the automation tools that stood the test of time, but is it the best because it has a large user base? That shouldn't be the only metric at play for a decision. Each automation tool has an edge over the other depending on the desired application.

Comment: @jjhelguero I agree with you, but he is asking for advice what tool to choose. He need to start with one of them, not with all the 3. So, based on his personal data and the advantage of Selenium I think this will be the right way to start with. In case he will need - he can in future switch to another tools, it's totally OK.

Comment: thank you guys. Based on my understanding, employers seem to focus on Selenium even though it may be not be as good, just because it has been in the market for a while to be a standard

Answer (score 1):

I think Protractor is being dropped by Angular in favor of Cypress.

Please see
[The State of end-to-end testing with Angular](https://blog.angular.io/the-state-of-end-to-end-testing-with-angular-d175f751cb9c)

> ...we’ve decided to deprecate Protractor

and [@cypress/schematic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/schematic).

#### Component testing

Also consider that Cypress has first-class component testing (as well as e2e testing) which has better speed than e2e but better coverage than unit testing.

See [Quickstart Angular](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/quickstart-angular)

and [Cypress Component Testing vs Angular Test Harness](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-component-testing-vs-angular-test-harness/)

[image]

Comment: I get that Cypress is more compact. Does that make it more efficient? Sometimes, lots of libraries can be heavy and slow down. and Hard to see the harness comparisons. Any way to see them clearly or a good example for better understanding?

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asking. How are you going to measure "efficient"?